# Drop timezone before format

Tags: momentjs

I want to add one second to random time in ISO format, e.g.

```
var t = "2015-01-13T00:00:00+11:00";
moment(t).add(1, "second").format(); // expected "2015-01-13T00:00:01+11:00", but get "2015-01-12T18:00:01+05:00"
```

So it converts `t` to *current browser timezone* (`+05:00` in my case) and only then adds a second.

How can I drop timezone before adding and return it after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

```
moment.parseZone(t).add("1", "second").format(); // "2015-01-13T00:00:01+11:00"
```